# Plugging UIPanGestureRecognizer to dismiss UIPageViewController with transition type UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uipageviewcontroller, uipangesturerecognizer

I am using a `UIPageViewController` to scroll through some view controllers. However, I need to dismiss the `UIPageViewController` at the beginning and end of the array of view controllers, ie, if while scrolling through page view controller, if we have reached the boundary of the view controller array, dismiss the view controller.

For the dismiss, I am using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` called `dismissPanGestureRecognizer`. This works wonderfully when the transition style of UIPageViewController is `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl`. In that case I can hook up my gestures like so-

in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[pageViewController.gestureRecognizers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIGestureRecognizer *gR, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    gR.delegate = self;
    [dismissPanGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:gR];
}];

self.view.gestureRecognizers = self.pageViewController.gestureRecognizers;
```

For the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` methods, its something like this-

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // If we are at the left boundary and this is a pan gesture going right-left,
    // return NO
    // Else If we are at the right boundary and this is a pan gesture going left-right,
    // return NO
    // Else return YES
}
```

So far so good. If its a pan gesture, we use it to dismiss only if page view controller gestures are not interested in it.

The problem occurs when the transition style is `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll`. In that case the `UIPageViewController` don't have any gesture recognizers. It looks like it gets implemented using an internal view (pageViewController.view.subviews) called `UIQueuingScrollView` which I would rather not muck around with.
What happens is that in scrolling transition type, at the boundary of the view controller, the scroll view just bounces, and the pan gesture recognizer never gets fired for dismissal.  I had tried setting the `bounces` property of UIQueuingScrollView to NO, and then the pages don't even change.

Next I tried adding a transparent `UIView` on top of the `UIPageViewController` view and then implementing `hitTest:withEvent:` on that, thinking I will forward the event to pageViewController only when it is not at the boundaries. But while it does give some degree of control on when to allow pages to turn, it stops other gestures to get passed to pageController views too (like tapping on a button, etc).

I am trying to find ways on how I can get my own UIPanGestureRecognizer to get fired when I reach the boundary of a UIPageViewController (UIPageViewControllerDataSource methods returns `nil`), when the transition style is `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll`.

I am currently testing on iOS6/iOS7.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve the desired effect by reacting to a `currentPageIndex` property you track on your `UIPageViewController` object or in the object that implements its `datasource`. Check this property and handle the dismissal when `currentPageIndex == 0 || n-1` inside of one of the `UIPageViewController` delegate methods (probably the latter of the two below):

```
#pragma mark - UIPageViewController Delegate

- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController willTransitionToViewControllers:(NSArray *)pendingViewControllers
{
    NSLog(@"will transition");
}

- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed
{
    NSLog(@"did finish animating");
}
```

Hopefully this helps...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This will allow me to know when to dismiss the view controller, which I was already able to get from `PageViewController`'s dataSource methods. But I don't see how I can use this to plug in my UIPanGestureRegocnizer to be used instead of the gesture being consumed by PageViewController's UIQueuingScrollView